# Minimal postgres instance for testing

Tags: java, postgresql, testing, jdbc

I have some code that interacts with postgres databases via JDBC.  However, for testing purposes I just want to quick way to create a new database and connect to it without having to modify my global postgres installation, manage users, etc.  How do people generally do this kind of testing?

Answer (score 8):

I'd locate the `initdb` executable and use it to create a new database instance temporary storage writeable by the current user. Since it's a test instance, use something like `initdb --auth=trust --username=postgres -D /path/to/temp/datadir` so the new database is set up to accept connections without requiring passwords.

Use `pg_ctl` to start the server, specifying a port to override the default set in the generated `postgresql.conf` and avoid conflicts.

Connect to the new database cluster and do whatever work is required. You'll want to connect as the user `postgres` first and run any required `CREATE USER` and `CREATE DATABASE` commands before handing control over to your test code.

Finally, use `pg_ctl` to stop it and finally delete the data directory.

All you need is `initdb` and `pg_ctl` on the `PATH`, and a helper class to manage the server.

See:

- [`initdb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)
- [`pg_ctl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html)

Answer (score 7):

There are several libraries that make create temporary instances of Postgres for testing easy:

- https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.postgresql
- https://github.com/TJC/Test-postgresql
- https://eradman.com/ephemeralpg (Disclosure: I am the author/maintainer)

All of these are designed shut down and remove the temporary database automatically. This is how you might use `pg_tmp(1)` to create a minimal Postgres instance from a Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class test_pg
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pg_tmp -t");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String pg_uri = "jdbc:" + input.readLine();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Using " + pg_uri);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(pg_uri);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select now()");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch(IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install an instance of Postgres in your home directory, running on a different port and under your user. See here for example:

http://www.bacula.org/manuals/en/catalog/catalog/Installi_Configur_PostgreS.html

You can also test your code on Heroku, depending on what it is. They give you a small virtual Postgres database for free.

Comment: Requiring a per user install for testing seems a bit heavyweight.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "per user." If there is just one user (i.e. you) and the server's postgres, it's no big deal. If the machine is accessed by tons of developers and each one has to do it *on this machine* then yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Virtual machine

You can configure ahead of time a [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (such as [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution), [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), etc.) with [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) installed. Use this template as an image to be launched as a virtual machine.

You can do this locally, using desktop virtualizes such as [*Parallels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac), [*Fusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion), or [*VirtualBox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox).

Or you can do this in VM service such as [DigitalOcean.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Ocean).

## Database migration tool

Once you VM is up and running (may take a minute), then use a [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_migration#Database_migration) tool such as [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to install your schema, tables, columns, and data.

These tools can [clear your database](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean) of content for repeated use. There is a setting to ensure this feature cannot be used in production(!).

Note that these tools can automate the creation of everything *within* a database, but cannot do the [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html). For that you will need to do some other scripting, or already have an empty test database created. And, as I said, you can clear the database for re-use.